# Does :sym.eql?("sym") misbehave in IronRuby?

Tags: ruby, ironruby

I just installed Mono 2.10 on my Mac and proceeded to run my [Ruby Koans](http://www.rubykoans.com/) which I had previously finished to see if IronRuby got the same results as Mac's native Ruby 1.8.7. One of the tests midway through failed, and the issue seems to be this:

In Ruby 1.8.7, the following expression is false:

```
:sym.eql?("sym")
=> false
```

However, in IronRuby, it is true. The version of IronRuby I'm running is 1.1.2.0, which apparently is comparable to Ruby 1.9.2, so I downloaded that to check - it gets the same behaviour as Ruby 1.8.7. Is this an issue with IronRuby's implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug according to the [Ruby Spec](http://rubyspec.org). The semantics of `#eql?` are that it is true if `==` is true **and** if the objects are of the same class.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I see someone has already opened an issue on IronRuby's codeplex page: http://ironruby.codeplex.com/workitem/6006